# Linear Algebra Notation $\{f \in C^1[-1,1]; f'(0) + \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \, dx=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand how to read the notation for this question (or answer it for that matter) for my university tutorial worksheet a few weeks ago:

It is given that a Vector space must satisfy the ten axioms that define a vector space, and it must be closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Determine if the following is a vector space:

$$V = \left\{f \in C^1[-1,1]; f'(0) + \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx=0\right\}$$

Comment: Are you sure it's a semicolon `;` and not a colon `:` in the definition of $V$? The latter is much more standard.

Comment: There are more questions with a similar layout that also have a semicolon, so I'm positive it's supposed to be a semicolon.

Comment: In proper MathJax usage, you don't exclude plus signs and things like $[-1,1]$ from what in set in MathJax, and the whole expression $\{f \in C^1[-1,1]; f'(0) + \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \, dx=0\}$ belongs between a single pair of dollar signs, not one pair for $f$, another for $\in$, another for $C^1$, etc.  I edited accordingly. Similarly: $$ V = \left\{f \in C^1[-1,1]; f'(0) + \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx=0\right\} $$

Comment: @ElijahMoore Interesting. Where are you from, if I may ask? I have never seen this notation.

Comment: @ClementC. I'm a first year student at the University of Newcastle in Australia, this is from their Math1220 Mathematical Discovery 2 course, covering Calculus and Linear Algebra.

Comment: @ClementC. : What is it in the notation that you think may not be known everywhere on Earth? $\qquad$

Comment: @ClementC. : The only thing in the notation that looks to me as if it may be less than universally standard is the use of a semicolon where I'm accustomed to seeing a colon or a vertical slash, and that usage does not impair understanding. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's the point, exactly. (I have seen $\mid$ or $:$ used as a delimiter, but never $;$; the rest is merely curiosity, I do agree with the fact that it's completely understandable. It messes up the spacing in $\LaTeX$, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $C^1[-1,1]$ is that set of all real-valued functions whose domain is the interval $[-1,1]$ and that are everywhere differentiable and whose derivatives are everywhere continuous.  Such functions are called continuously differentiable functions.  So you need to check that the sum of two continuously differentiable functions is continuously differentiable.  Two theorems from calculus get you that:

- One theorem says the sum of two differentiable functions is differentiable.
- Another says the sum of two continuous functions is continuous. (Apply this one to the derivatives.)

Then you need to check that if $$ f'(0) + \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx=0\quad\text{ and }\quad g'(0) + \int_{-1}^1 g(x)\,dx=0 $$ **then** $$ (f+g)'(0) + \int_{-1}^1 (f+g)(x)\,dx = 0. $$

That shows that the set in question is closed under addition.

The proof that it is also closed under scalar multiplication is very similar.

Since the set is a subset of something that you already know is a vector space, you don't need to go through the whole list of axioms, but you do need to check closure under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: I got around to doing this, splitting the two:

$(f+g)′(0)+\int_{1}^{-1}(f+g)(x)dx=f'(0)+\int_{1}^{-1}(f(x)dx)+g'(0)+\int_{1}^{-1}(g(x)dx)=0$

$a(f′(0))+\int_{1}^{-1}a(f(x)dx)=a(f′(0))+a\int_{1}^{-1}f(x)dx=a[f′(0)+\int_{1}^{-1}f(x)dx]=0$

Answer (score 3):

The set $V$ consists of all continuously differentiable functions on the interval $[-1,1]$ (this is the $f \in C^1[-1,1]$ part) that satisfy

$$ f'(0) + \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \, dx = 0. $$

Since $V$ consists of (let's say) real functions $f \colon [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we can add two such functions as follows:

$$ (f + g)(x) := f(x) + g(x) $$

We can also multiply a function by a scalar $a \in \mathbb{R}$ resulting in a new function defined by

$$ (af)(x) := af(x). $$

Now you need to check whether $(V,+,\cdot)$ satisfies the axioms of being a vector space. Two important things to check are whether the addition and the scalar multiplication result in elements of $V$ (that is, whether $f,g \in V$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ implies that $f + g$ and $cf$ belong to $V$). In fact, since $V$ is a subset of the collection of all functions $f \colon [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is a vector space with the operations defined above, those two things together with the fact that $V$ is non-empty guarantee that $V$ is a vector space (as all other axioms follows from the corresponding axioms that hold for the ambient vector space).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this is still going way over my head. 

What does the $C^1[-1,1]$ actually mean?

I understand $f$ is some element contained in this thing, but what exactly is the thing?!

[-1,1] specifies the interval, so does $C^1$ just mean "all continuously differentiable elements" which in this case is $f$?

(

Comment: @ElijahMoore Yep. One denotes by $C([-1,1]) = C^0([-1,1])$ all continuous functions $f \colon [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, by $C^1([-1,1])$ all continuously differentiable functions (that is, all continuous functions such that $f'$ exists and also continuous), etc.

Comment: The main thing he needs to check is whether the sum and the scalar multiple are in fact members of the set that was defined. $\qquad$

Comment: I've down-voted this answer because it did not say that one needs to check that the sum and the scalar multiple of members of $V$ itself belongs to $V$, and that indeed, that is the main point.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are of course correct and this is something I should have stretched. I've tried to delete my answer but since it was accepted, I edited it instead to emphasize this point.